# Show android Popup(Help - overlay view) view

Tags: android, view, popup

Need implement view  with different help arrows, like on page:  [image: help popup on page]

But I have not any idea how to implement it. Made some popup windows, what was attached for some views, but this confused me.
Will be glad any proposals how to realized it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this **ShowcaseView**

designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps.

Check repo https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: Thank you for link, this is not what I looking for, but can help me implement  view myself.